# creating three dots vertically with span and align them

Tags: html, css, alignment, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create three vertical dots and align the bottom left of my container with css and bootstrap 5. exactly like the pic below:

[image]

my HTML and CSS:

```css
.dot {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #76b3fe, #8680e4);
}

.selected-dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #97cdfe;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider-bg-1 d-flex align-items-end">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center pt-4 pt-lg-0 order-2 order-lg-1">
        <h1 class="head-font-size">Choose a powerful design for your Start-up</h1>
        <h6 claas="caption-text-color">Get your freebie template now</h6>
        <div class="d-lg-flex">
          <div class="mt-5"><button class="my-btn" type="submit">Discover</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 order-1 order-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img src="Assets/home-slider/slider-m-1.png" class="img-fluid img-slider" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="dot selected-dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</section>
```

this is my output
[image]

how can i align the vertically and move them to bottom left of container? because when i use div for wrapping they disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st: wrap the dots in a container. I used a section with the class: `.dot-wrapper`.
2nd: give the wrapper a `width: min-content;`. With that, it will only be as wide as the seclected dot.
3rd: to cenetr the dots, give them a margin left and right of auto;

```css
.dot {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #76b3fe, #8680e4);
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.selected-dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #97cdfe;
}

.dot-wrapper {
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider-bg-1 d-flex align-items-end">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center pt-4 pt-lg-0 order-2 order-lg-1">
        <h1 class="head-font-size">Choose a powerful design for your Start-up</h1>
        <h6 claas="caption-text-color">Get your freebie template now</h6>
        <div class="d-lg-flex">
          <div class="mt-5"><button class="my-btn" type="submit">Discover</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12 order-1 order-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img src="Assets/home-slider/slider-m-1.png" class="img-fluid img-slider" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="dot-wrapper">
    <div class="dot selected-dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

it's quite easy, you can wrap the dots with a `div container` like this

```
<!--Column Dots -->
<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot selected-dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

and style the container as below

```
.dot-container{
width: 15px;
display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-items:center;
}
```

and for better styling. give `dot` class some amrgin like `margin: 3px 0;`

here is a codpen : https://codepen.io/shammlo/pen/QWKggNX?editors=1100